# how to crawl subcategories from a page?

Tags: jsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to write a topical crawler in java. I already wrote a crawler for amazon which traverses the whole website and gives me all the links.
Now i'm kind of stuck with writing a crawler, which crawls only certain areas. My goal is to crawl amazon and only get articles from a certain categegoy.
Has anybody some thoughts about this?
Thanks in advance. I appreciate every help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inspect the URLs, if they have any hints which category the referenced items are assigned to.

Comment: Hm i already tried something like that, but the URl gives not much information

Comment: in fact you can see the category in the search-query.maybe it'll work with that.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a naive idea. Every retail website, like amazon, has filter option.Most likely the parameters are passed using GET in the url. You can play with that, to get the desired result. In case its AJAX , follow the AJAX call.